# Why does my app get "stuck" when scrolling on Safari?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, safari

A website I recently built is getting "stuck" when scrolling on mobile Safari. Once it gets stuck, you can't scroll (it just bounces back), and have to click around frantically where it after while fixes itself.

I have another site created with very similar components that doesn't have this problem, and I've troubleshooted this tons already by process of elimination, but have yet to find the cause.

Steps to reproduce:

- Visit https://about.wrightwaystore.com and click & scroll around a little, and you should see what I mean.

Uploaded a video to my public S3: https://general-public-aw.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/silly-safari-bug.mp4

Does anyone have any ideas what this might be?

Any assistance is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I can see it happening on first load on my iPhone. Weird indeed. It seems the browser initially thinks the body has no height. I’d need to inspect on my laptop later..

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same problem with the chessboard page on my chess site. Example: https://www.chessmail.de/game/LsKu6nqqzz5M

Comment: I dont remember the exact solution, but it might have been to do with one tag being inside another tag, where it shouldn't have been. I think once I put them one after the other, it was fine. Dont remember what tags though. This could be wrong, it was a long time ago. But might have been it